# Gap in UI of Border layout in codenameone

Tags: lwuit, codenameone, lwuit-form

I try to make a frame having border layout.
In it i have 3 container- top, center and bottom . all three container has 3 different type of background. but when i see them there is little gap between these layouts which makes UI little separated and not looks good.

Please help me that how can i consume these gaps and my container looks merged.

Thanks in advance...

[image]

Please check this image. it explains u gap. i have mentioned it in red color. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the margin for the Containers to 0. A screenshot/code might be helpful to pinpoint this.

Comment: please check attached image and share me your views. i have checked code there i no margen

Comment: While I can see the gap it doesn't really help without understanding how your code is structured. I suggest you open the Component Inspector in the current version of the simulator and look at the component hierarchy then set the margin/padding of the components to 0 until you locate the culprit.

Comment: Hi Sir I have check it and try to make changes in theme too then i found that lets take two container, container a and b , if both container's UIID has derive is checked then there is no gap but if derive is not checked and some background is set then there is gap. Please help.

Comment: If you define a margin there will be a gap, its hard for me to help you this way. You need to explain what exactly did you customize for every one of these containers. Screenshots from the designer could help